# Наследование класса

Tags: c++, проектирование

Есть проект, пишется другими разработчиками, исходников у меня нет и не будет, максимум предоставят объектный файл. Я со своей стороны пишу к нему модулёк, который собирается в виде отдельной dll, и реализует определенный функционал, путем наследования их класса и переопределения некоторых виртуальных методов, но сложность в том, что их класс "тянет" за собой очень много не нужного для меня (библиотеки, реализации и т.д.).

Есть ли какая-то возможность отнаследоваться так, чтобы не включать всё это в свой проект, например используя объектный файл или как-то еще.

Comment: Если кратко - этот вопрос стоит обсудить как раз с командой разработчиков. Вопрос очень специфичен, и без примеров и предметной области ничего толком ответить не получится. Могу посоветовать почитать и посмотреть в сторону динамической линковки и дальнего связывания, а также подробнее изучить формат DLL и специфику сборки.

Либо попробуйте сформулировать вопрос более конкретно.

Comment: Если вы наследуете от их класса то все наследованные методы этого класса должны быть полностью скомпилированы, т.е. все завивимости которые тянут эти методы должны быть слинкованы. С другой стороны если все методы базового класса лишние и в вашей программе они не нужны, то вы можете просто поменять объявление их класса убрав все лишние методы только оставив в точности такими же как у них поля-члены с данными. Также все виртуальные методы должны остаться как есть чтобы таблица виртуальных методов была ровно такая же.

Comment: Т.е. суть такая что вам нужно в точности сохранить структуру объекта их класса как она выглядит в ОЗУ, а в ОЗУ она состоит из членов-данных плюс виртуальной таблицы. Все невиртуальные методы в бинарном образе объекта не находятся и их смело можно удалить.

Comment: @ Arty OneSoul, спасибо за интересный вариант, над этим стоит помыслить.

Comment: @DenisScherbakov Кстати это зависит от компилятора, но вообще компилятору ничего не мешает чтобы неиспользуемые функции и методы полностью исключить из результирующего бинарника, т.е. по идее если компилятор хороший то он все методы которые вы не вызвали они должны быть полностью удалены включая их зависимости. Но на самом деле вроде MSVC компилятор всё равно большую часть неиспользуемых зависимостей всё равно требует слинковать, нужно смотреть.

Comment: @DenisScherbakov Кстати я забыл раньше сказать, я писал что виртуальные методы все нужно оставить в таком же порядке как есть они, но на самом деле достаточно заменить все их определения на пустые объявления т.е. указать "= 0" в конце виртуальных функций. Т.е. я к тому чтобы удалить связь с их реализацией которая может тянуть много чего. Т.е. у вас получится чистый класс с "=0" виртуальными функциями и членами-данными. Получается такой класс вообще ни одной функции тянуть не будет из зависимостей, пустышка получится.